# Recursive Binary Search for Spellcheck is missing some words

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree, spell-checking

I have a dictionary file that contains a list of words, and I read that file into the array list `sArray`. I then have a book where I use a string parser to take every string from this book and send it to the binary search method, `bSearch`. `bSearch` will use a recursive binary search to determine if key is found in the array `sArray` containing the dictionary. If the word is not found it will print out that the word is possibly misspelled.

My issue is, I am getting outputs of words that I know for a fact are in my dictionary array. I have  verified that the words are being read properly so the issue boils down to the navigating over `sArray` with `bSearch`. I am unsure what is wrong with the code. Some examples of false positives are listed below.

Here is a link to a paste dump of my dictionary; you should be able to search for these words below and find them. https://paste.ee/p/wp3qh

Sample output:

The resulting output is still all false positives

> ebracteate is possibly mispelled
>
> Phaca is possibly mispelled
>
> holmberry is possibly mispelled
>
> sraddha is possibly mispelled

```
public class Program2 {

private int mid;

public Program2() {
    mid = 0;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    File inf = new File("dictonary.txt");
    ArrayList<String> sArray = new ArrayList<>();
    Program2 a = new Program2();
    a.readDictonary(sArray);
  
    Collections.sort(sArray, String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
   
    int correctRec = 0;
    int incorrectRec = 0;
    int correctW = 0;
    int incorrectW = 0;
   
    FileInputStream infO = new FileInputStream(new File("oliver.txt"));
    char let;
    String str = "";
    int n = 0;
    while ((n = infO.read()) != -1) {
        let = (char) n;

        if (Character.isLetter(let)) {
            str += Character.toLowerCase(let);
        }

        if ((Character.isWhitespace(let) || let == '-') && !str.isEmpty()) {

            // Write code to insert str in to your tree here
            if (a.bSearch(sArray, str, 0, sArray.size()) >= 0) {
                correctRec++;
            } else {
                incorrectRec++;
            }

            str = "";
        }
    }
    infO.close();
    a.print(correctRec, incorrectRec);
}

public void print(int correctRec, int incorrectRec) {
    System.out.println("Out of total words " + (incorrectWords + correctWords));
    System.out.println("Correct " + correctWords);
    System.out.println("Incorrect " + incorrectWords);
    System.out.println("Total number of recursive steps is " + (correctRec + incorrectRec));
    System.out.println("The average number of comparisons for a word found = " + correctRec / correctWords);
    System.out.println("The average number of comparisons for a word not found = " + incorrectRec / incorrectWords);
}

public void readDictonary(ArrayList<String> sArray) {
    try {
        File f = new File("dictionary.txt");
        Scanner inf = new Scanner(f);
        while (inf.hasNext()) {
            sArray.add(inf.nextLine());
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("The dictonary file was not found");
    }
}

public int bSearch(ArrayList<String> sArray, String key, int lowIndex, int highIndex) {
    if (lowIndex > highIndex) {
        System.out.println(sArray.get(mid) + " is possibly mispelled");
        incorrectWords++;
        return rec * -1;
    }

    mid = (lowIndex + highIndex) / 2;

    if (sArray.get(mid).compareToIgnoreCase(key) == 0) {
        correctWords++;

        return rec;
    } else if (sArray.get(mid).compareToIgnoreCase(key) > 0) {
        rec++;
        return bSearch(sArray, key, lowIndex, mid - 1);
    } else {
        rec++;
        return bSearch(sArray, key, mid + 1, highIndex);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely not in your algorithm, which looks mostly fine, but in your error message

```
System.out.println(sArray.get(mid) + " is possibly mispelled");
```

Did you mean

```
System.out.println(key + " is possibly mispelled");
```

?

Regarding your binary search, the only concern that I have is that your highIndex seems to be inclusive, but when you call your `bSearch` routine, you pass `sArray.size()`, which is exclusive. I suspect that it will lead to a crash if you try to search for a word that is lexicographically bigger than anything in the dictionary. You need to uss `sArray.size() - 1` as `highIndex` when you call your binary search.

Comment: I can't believe I was printing out the wrong error the entire time, thank you so much!